# create 2D array using multiple 1D array having different size using python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, image-processing

How can i make a 2d array using four 1d arrays `arr1[] arr2[] arr3[] arr4[]` of different sized, like `arr1 = [1,2,3] arr2 = [4,5] arr3=[1,2,6,7] arr4=[1,3,8,7,5,4,0] arr4=[1,2,4,3,5]` to create image and it should looks like:

[image]

Comment: Those are sets, not arrays. Also, please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: They where sets before being edited @yasin